# Разница между синтаксисом захвата this в лямбде

Tags: c++, lambda

В чём разница между следующими захватами в лямбде?

```
struct A { 
  void f(int x) {
    [=]{};        // (1)
    [=, this]{};  // (2)
    [=, *this]{}; // (3)
  }
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: Думаю лучше читать литературу(статьи), получите более обширную информацию. Например  https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/455978/

Answer (score 0):

`*this` захватывает текущий объект по значению, т.е. копирует `*this` в лямбду.

`this` захватывает его по ссылке.

`&` по умолчанию захватывает `this`, если он нужен (по ссылке, как и все остальное).

`=` почему-то тоже захватывает `this` по ссылке (если он нужен), хотя все остальное - по значению. Начиная с C++20, захват `this` через `=` стал устаревшим. Видимо когда-то хотят переделать на нормальный захват по значению.